# SSID on the repeater bridge router

Tags: dd-wrt, bridge, repeater, bridge-router

I have a Linksys WRT400N dual band router and I want to use it as a repeater bridge for my main AT&T router. Now I kind of get it working with dd-wrt firmware. I use the latest v24 sp2 firmware and according to [this article](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge) it should have a `Repeater Bridge` mode, but mine doesn't. Mine has `Client` and `Client Bridge (Routed)` and few other modes. And my router is dual-band which is not included in the tutorial. Now I use `Client Bridge (Router)` mode on the 2.4GHz channel, and I left the 5GHz channel untouched in the `AP` mode with its own SSID. And it actually worked. When I connect to the 5GHz channel I actually have Internet connection. Is this essentially the so-called `Repeater Bridge` mode?

Now my question is can I set the SSID on the 5GHz channel to be the same as the SSID on the main AT&T router? Will it mess up my network? And if it could work, how do I know which router my device is connected to? Do they automatically switch to the stronger signal?

---

#### EDIT

To be clear everything is under the same subnet 192.168.1.xxx.

I tested the speed when connected to the bridge router and the main router, they are pretty much the same. So this setup is actually better than the `repeater bridge`, which cuts speed in half I believe.

Comment: frankly, if you set different SSIDs you can tell which its connected to, & force it over if it hangs onto the distant one too long. Same SSID, it's out of your hands.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this essentially the so-called Repeater Bridge mode?

Sort of. You are right that a *Repeater Bridge mode* allows both wired and wireless clients to join a router which is linked via wifi to the primary router. The difference here is that the *Repeater Bridge* mode uses the same interface (or NIC) to connect to downstream clients and to the upstream router, so that it is receiving for half of the time, and transmitting for another half of the time. This can be achieved also with a normal pc, but most routers cannot do that.

Also, it is not clear from what you say whether clients of the 5GHz wireless are in the same subnet as wired clients: if they are, then you have some kind of bridge between LAN-side ethernet and wifi, otherwise you surely do not. So, once again, you **may** have a repeater bridge router, but then again you may not.

> SSID

I will side with Temujin here: giving the same name is probably inconvenient. But I will also add that it might be misleading, if you do not have a bridge between LAN-side ethernet and 5GHZ wifi, because in this case clients of the main router's wifi, and of the secondary router's 5GHz wifi will be in different subnets. You would then have an impossible situation with static IPs, and possibly some difficulties even with DHCP clients.

> And if it could work, how do I know which router my device is connected to? Do they automatically switch to the stronger signal?

No, wifi clients do not automatically shift to the stronger signal. And, if you **do** have a bridged repeater, it would be more complex to find out wich router you are connected to. In this case, you would have to check the MAC address of the AP, with a command like (in Linux):

```
  sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
```

which gives you all relevant details.

Comment: 1. All router/devices are in 192.168.1.xxx, so I guess they're all in the same subnet? 2. I probably will leave it as a different SSID then.